# Error connecting to MSSQL server from Linux

Tags: sql-server-2014, linux, odbc

A colleague is trying to connect to the MS SQL Server Instance from linux using ODBC driver 17 and get's the below error.

> ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The Connection string appears as below:

```
SQL_SERVER = 'Myserver'
SQL_DB = 'Mydatabase'

'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=MYServer;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes'
```

Comment: Is the port default 1433 ?

Comment: I've tried 1434 & 1433 ports obtained from the error log and both have failed

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046158/pyodbc-login-timeout-error). Apparently a change to the settings and the ODBC fixed the issue, you may want to give a try.

Also I'm seeing `Trusted_Connection=yes` is the authentication possible between the linux and the SQL Server? If not maybe you should go with SQL Authentication.